# Very easy question of ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can we introduce $R/I$, where $R$ is a ring and $I$ is a sub-ring of $R$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well you can, but it won't be a ring under the natural operations unless $I$ is an ideal. Also, please make your question title a little more relevant.

Comment: Can it still partition the R into the same cardinality parts ? Thank you.

Comment: @mahrap since a ring $R$ is an abelian group under $+$, and a subring $I$ is a subgroup, all group-theoretic results about quotients apply (but, as Prahlad points out, there is not a natural ring structure on the quotient). In particular, the cosets of $I$ partition $R$ and all have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

If $I \subset R$ is an extension of rings, all you can do is saying that they have an $I$-module structure, hence you can build the usual $I$-module $R/I$.